# Short story where astronauts can't reconcile different numbers of legs on creatures on a planet they landed on

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Ends in narrator concluding it's some kind of alien zoo and they're a new addition. I recall a line about speculating about an identification plaque for visitors labeled something like "Earth Man - Sol III".

Comment: Your question is likely answered by [Sci-fi story about astronauts using their knowledge of evolution to figure out they're in a space zoo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/78715/98028) and [Short story or book about a space crew on a broken ship who were capturing alien animals for a zoo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36834/98028). Please take a look and confirm (or deny); this way, we'll be able to close this question, not as a punishment of any sort, but to follow the bookkeeping procedures of this site, and redirect future askers with an already well-elaborated and maintained answer.

Comment: @Jenayah Last line of that story: "EARTHMEN. Native Habitat, Sol III."

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thank you.